# Refreshing parent page from child on close in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have this code, that works properly in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

```
$(window).unload(function () {
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
        });
```

This code is in a pop-up page. I want the parent page to reload after closing the pop-up (pressing X on the browser). I googled everywhere but found nothing of use. Tried with setTimeout, with window.top /window.parent etc... Nothing seems to work on chrome. Thank you

Comment: Tried window.opener.reload() ?